# Background Wallpaper changing automatically after Lock Screen Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, desktop-background

guys! I'm new to ubuntu and something has been happening lately.

Every time I press the Lock Screen button on the quick settings panel (top right) and then "wake up" my machine, the wallpaper automatically changes into a white solid color (which is not the color I chose, mine is solid black). I noticed this started to happen after I tried to install the nvidia driver. My ubuntu version is the 18.04. How can I make this stop?

Thanks